# What does 'Reno-era' policy mean?

Tags: meaning, adjectives, compounds

I saw the following sentence in today's Washington Post article. What does 'Reno-era' policy mean? It's a new word to me. Can somebody tell?

> Reno-era policy kept Jared Loughner off FBI gun list. 
>   An old policy memo from the Clinton administration paved the way for accused Arizona gunman Jared Loughner to buy his first firearm.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"Reno-era" refers to the time when Janet Reno was the Attorney General of the US.

The second sentence of the Washington Post article mentions "then-Attorney General" Reno

> Put in place by then-Attorney General Janet Reno, the policy prohibited the military from reporting certain drug abusers to the FBI, which manages the national list of prohibited gun-buyers, federal officials said.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Janet_Reno)

> Janet Reno is a former Attorney General of the United States (1993–2001). She was nominated by President Bill Clinton on February 11, 1993, and confirmed on March 11. She was the first female Attorney General and the second longest serving Attorney General after William Wirt.

EDIT: clarifed and moved WAPO article to top of answer

Comment: Thank you very much John. I thought 'Reno'is a common noun, and couldn't associate it with a person's (then-Attorney General's )name. It's the weak point of, and a hard barrier for foreign learner of English like me with little knowledge of politics, culture, history and many other things of U.S. and western world. I think that's why I am on this forum. - Yoichi

Comment: @Yoichi yes, culture (if you can call what the US has culture ;-)) is important. Just check (where, I don't know myself actually) how many (US) idioms come from baseball. Just knowing the *basics* of it (very basically what the object of the game is, what some things are called, and such) helps a lot in understanding these idioms.

Comment: And it helps to know that in English (not sure if that's more of a US thing), writers love to play with idioms/proverbs.  Like what Howard Tayler posted on Twitter recently:  "The political punditry over the AZ shooting is a clear case of the crackpot calling the whole other kettle of fish black."

Comment: @Yoichi: you are welcome. I clarified my answer to point out that the Washington Post (WAPO) article does explain who "Reno" was, but it was easy to miss.

Comment: To all answerers: I pressed 'Bounty Button' without knowing what it means at all this morning (Jan.23), simply because it appeared in the question list, and I lost 50 reputation points instantly! I don't know why. It seems "Bounty" means disapproving answers answerers kindly gave me. It's not totally what I mean.  Idon't still understand the gimick of how "Bounty" works, what's it good for.If I gave you inconvenience by this action, I deeply apologize all of answerers to my question. Can somebody kindly explain me about the mechanics of 'Bounty' to my e-mail adress? yoioishi@jcom.home.ne.jp

Comment: @Yoichi: the bounty system is explained in the [site FAQ](http://english.stackexchange.com/faq).  If the language used there is difficult for a non-native speaker, let us know what points are unclear and we can clarify them here :-)

Comment: @Yoichi Oishi: A bounty is a reward, or prize, for achieving a goal.  If you offer a bounty on a question, you give up some of your reputation as a reward for answering the question successfully.  The bounty-points go to whoever you nominate to receive them, or to the answer with the highest vote count at the end of the time frame.

Comment: Then I would like to dedicate the bounty to the first answerer, John Satta. How can present it to him?

Comment: @Yoichi: awarding the bounty is usually automatic when you accept an answer.  Perhaps since the answer was accepted before you set the bounty, you might have to de-accept it and then accept it again?  (So: click the green check-mark underneath its vote count twice; the first click should de-accept it, the second click should re-accept it and hopefully award him the bounty? I’m not certain this is exactly right, but it’s what I would try if I were in your position.)

Comment: @Yoichi Oishi: There should be another button below the checkmark. That is the one that awards the bounty.

Comment: @PLL: That's how things used to work, but the bounty system has been decoupled from the accepted-answer system. You can even place a bounty on someone else's question if you like.